# What's wrong with this basic shell script exporting something

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

```
$cat test
export var=value
$./test
$echo $var
```

I get nothing. I was expecting to see value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case `test` is being run in a separate shell, a child of your shell. A child can never modify the environment of the parent. So when the child exits `var` is lost.

If you want to run the script in the current shell try:

```
source ./test
```

Also, it's usually a poor idea to name your scripts "test". Many unices have `/usr/bin/test`.

Comment: But I thought the purpose of using export was that with this you could make a local variable, a global one and make it visible outside.

Comment: @p2pnode You thought wrong. The purpose of export is to make that variable available *to the children*, not to the parent.